# How can i get coordinates from a figure Canvas class?

Tags: python, pyqt5

i want to create a function that when u mouse click a point in the map, returns x,y values

```
lonGrid, latGrid = np.meshgrid(self.lonBathymetry[lon_inds[0 [0:-1:stepLon]], self.latBathymetry[lat_inds[0][0:-1:stepLat]])
    bathymetry = self.gb.variables['elevation'][ lat_inds[0][0:-1:stepLat] , lon_inds[0][0:-1:stepLon]] 

    self.m  = Basemap(ax=self.axes, projection='cyl',llcrnrlat=lat_min,urcrnrlat=lat_max,\
        llcrnrlon=lon_min,urcrnrlon=lon_max,resolution=res)

    xi, yi =self.m(lonGrid, latGrid)

def mousePressEvent(self, event):

    lonGrid= self.canvas.lonGrid
    latGrid= self.canvas.latGrid

    x = event.latGrid()
    y = event.lonGrid()
```

Comment: Can you edit this to have a minimum reproducible example? For my answer I assumed you're working with a matplotlib canvas, but that could be the wrong answer if you're using something else. It will also help other people find the answer to your question more easily.

https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

If this is a matplotlib canvas, the coordinates should be available in `event.x` and `event.y`.

Source: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/users/event_handling.html

Comment: it is a canvas that uses other lists for x and y data... how can i do it?

Comment: i tried your solution but i get this error.. 'bool' object has no attribute 'x'